# Swift 2 Error: .alloc() is unavailable in Swift: Use object initializers instead

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

After migrating to Swift2 getting following error:
.alloc() is unavailable in Swift: Use object initializers instead. Any help appreciated.  Thank you

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])  {

    element = elementName

    if (element as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
        elements = NSMutableDictionary.alloc()
        elements = [:]
        ftitle = NSMutableString.alloc()
        ftitle = ""
        link = NSMutableString.alloc()
        link = ""
        fdescription = NSMutableString.alloc()
        fdescription = ""
        fdate = NSMutableString.alloc()
        fdate = ""
        fcontent = NSMutableString.alloc()
        fcontent = ""
    }

}    

  func loadRssRefresh(data: NSURL) {


    let myParser : XmlParserManager = XmlParserManager.alloc().initWithURL(data) as! XmlParserManager

    myFeed = myParser.feeds

    tableView.reloadData()


    self.refresher.endRefreshing()


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
elements = NSMutableDictionary()
ftitle = NSMutableString()
```

Answer (score 2):

> .alloc() is unavailable in Swift: Use object initializers instead

This error message is pretty descriptive. It means that you shouldn't use `alloc` in Swift.

You could initialise your string that way:

```
let str = NSMutableString()
```

But you can also use a Swift string:

```
var str = ""
```